# Are there any limitations of frequently using "position" tag in CSS instead of using "margin" and "padding" tags?

Tags: html, css

I've been working with HTML and CSS for a while now.
Every time I work in CSS, I have a feeling that I'm not "doing it right".

For instance, when positioning different divs and elements on a webpage, I use "position: absolute" and "position: relative" quite often.
This can sometimes be very tedious to find the "right" position and results in very ugly numbers, such as:

```css
position: relative; 
width: 1300px; 
height: -720px;
```

In addition to above, it also makes it very difficult to edit said divs and elements later on if I change my mind about their appearance or position.
I've watched a lot of tutorials on YouTube where people use "margin" and "padding" tags to position the elements on their websites.

I'm very confused by this since those tags are supposed to be used for creating space around elements and not actually change their position.
The strange thing is, that it is much easier to edit the website using "margin" and "padding" tags later on, if you change your mind about the appearance/positioning of those elements since they won't move around and overlap each other.

I apologize for the long query but this has been bothering me a lot lately and I would appreciate any advice regarding the positioning of elements in CSS.

Thank you

Comment: There are lots of different ways to apply layouts using CSS, and different techniques are useful for different things. Flexbox and Grid are often far more useful than margins, padding or positioning. You don't really have a problem specific enough to give a good answer for.

Comment: Try to spend some time learning bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest distinction between `position` and `margin` or `padding` is that when you set the `position` to `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`, the element is taken out of the "normal flow" of the document and placed in its own layer. This is what allows you to use the `z-index` property and stack elements on top of each other. This has dramatic advantages when the elements in question are going to be dynamically sized or animated because doing so won't cause all other elements in the document to have to "re-flow", nor will the entire document have to "re-paint". In fact, when working with dynamic sizing or animations it is strongly recommended that you take elements out of the flow this way or performance can suffer.

Beyond this, [understanding how `absolute`, `relative` and `fixed` positioning work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is essential.

**Absolute Positioning** positions the element relative to its nearest ancestor that, itself, has been manually positioned or the `body` element if no ancestor has been positioned. The element is taken out of the flow and any space the element was taking up in that flow is removed.

**Relative Positioning** positions the element as an offset to its original location in the normal flow, but leaves the original space that the element took up in the document even though the element is now in its own layer.

**Fixed Positioning** is similar to absolute, except that the position is not relative to anything. It is fixed at an exact location you specify.

While all of these will pull the element into its own layer, how the layers are stacked (via **["stacking contexts"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)**) are dependent upon which type of positioning you've used and the structure of the elements being positioned.

These are the reasons to use `position`. If you are not in need of new layers, using CSS [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) are tools that can offer alternative ways to design a layout.

**`margin` and `padding` should really not be used for the layout itself. They are used for small tweaks within a layout.**

In summary, the default way the a browser lays out the contents of a page is the **[CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)**, but using CSS `position` is one way to have certain content use that box model in different layers from the main content. CSS floats offer another, separate layout algorithm  and Flexbox offers yet another. In the near future, the **[CSS Grid specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)** will be standardized and yet another layout paradigm will be available.

But `margin` and `padding` are not layout models. They are just tools to use in whatever layout model you happen to be using.